# How to Set up Bulk email on Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: email

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. I am connected to a dynamic IP-Based commercial internet connection.

I want to set up a bulk email setup like interspire. Is it possible and what are the key pointers which may be used to implement the same?

Thanks In advance

Comment: http://www.unimailer.com/buy.html free for home usage. interspire is webbased so OS independent(?) No need to set it up..

Comment: How to install unimailer.tar.gz on ubuntu . No documentation available

Comment: see the text below the download? "Other platforms :

Each installation will create an unimailer installation directory and a desktop link as possible to the running application. The bin directory from the installation directory contains the main unimailer application. If you meet difficulties to run unimailer, the installation directory contains also a simple bash and batch script to run it : run.sh (you must be in the bin directory) for Linux/Unix platforms or run.bat for Windows. "

Comment: The documentation mentioned on the site is not enough for a new ubuntu user . is there any other place which shows how to install this software tar.gz. i mean step by step solution. thanks for all your support friend